# StackWidget Second Page Incorrect Layout

Tags: c++, qt

I have two custom widgets in a QStackWidget. The first page is always in the correct layout, but the second page is not. If I switch the order of what is first shown, the formerly incorrectly laid out widget is correctly laid out. Below are files to replicate the behaviour.

MainWindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="CentralWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="name">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Main Window</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>CentralWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>centralwidget.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

CentralWidget.hi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>CentralWidget</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="CentralWidget">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QStackedWidget" name="stackedWidget">
     <property name="currentIndex">
      <number>0</number>
     </property>
     <widget class="CustomAWidget" name="page"/>
     <widget class="CustomBWidget" name="page_2"/>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="showPage1">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Show Page 1</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="showPage2">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Show Page 2</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>CustomAWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>customawidget.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
  <customwidget>
   <class>CustomBWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>custombwidget.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

CentralWidget.cpp

```
#include "centralwidget.h"

CentralWidget::CentralWidget(QWidget* parent) :
    QWidget{parent}
{
    this->setupUi(this);
    connect(
        this->showPage1,
        &QPushButton::clicked,
        this,
        [this] ()
        {
            this->page_2->hide();
            this->page->show();
        }
    );
    connect(
        this->showPage2,
        &QPushButton::clicked,
        this,
        [this] ()
        {
            this->page->hide();
            this->page_2->show();
        }
    );
}
```

CentralWidget.h

```
#ifndef CENTRALWIDGET_H
#define CENTRALWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

#include "ui_CentralWidget.h"

class CentralWidget : public QWidget, Ui::CentralWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CentralWidget(QWidget* parent);
};

#endif // CENTRALWIDGET_H
```

CustomAWidget.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>CustomAWidget</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="CustomAWidget">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="customAWidgetLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="name">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Custom Widget A</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
     <property name="widgetResizable">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>267</width>
        <height>280</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="scrollAreaLayout">
       <item>
        <spacer name="scrollAreaWidgetSpacer">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>259</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

CustomAWidget.cpp

```
#include "customawidget.h"

#include <QLabel>

CustomAWidget::CustomAWidget()
{
    this->setupUi(this);

    for (auto i{0} ; i < 100 ; ++i)
        this->scrollAreaLayout->insertWidget(
            this->scrollAreaLayout->indexOf(this->scrollAreaWidgetSpacer),
            new QLabel{QStringLiteral("Label %1").arg(i), this}
        );
}
```

CustomAWidget.h

```
#ifndef CUSTOMAWIDGET_H
#define CUSTOMAWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

#include <ui_CustomAWidget.h>

class CustomAWidget : public QWidget, Ui::CustomAWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CustomAWidget();
};

#endif // CUSTOMAWIDGET_H
```

CustomWidgetB.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>CustomBWidget</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="CustomBWidget">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="CustomBWidgetLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="name">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Custom Widget B</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
     <property name="widgetResizable">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>268</width>
        <height>280</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="scrollAreaLayout">
       <item>
        <spacer name="scrollAreaWidgetSpacer">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>259</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

CustomWidgetB.cpp

```
#include "custombwidget.h"

#include <QLabel>

CustomBWidget::CustomBWidget()
{
    this->setupUi(this);

    for (auto i{0} ; i < 100 ; ++i)
        this->scrollAreaLayout->insertWidget(
            this->scrollAreaLayout->indexOf(this->scrollAreaWidgetSpacer),
            new QLabel{QStringLiteral("Label %1").arg(i), this}
        );
}
```

CustomWidgetB.h

```
#ifndef CustomBWIDGET_H
#define CustomBWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

#include <ui_CustomBWidget.h>

class CustomBWidget : public QWidget, Ui::CustomBWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CustomBWidget();
};

#endif // CustomBWIDGET_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(Demo VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.h
        mainwindow.ui
        centralwidget.h centralwidget.cpp CentralWidget.ui
        customawidget.h customawidget.cpp CustomAWidget.ui
        custombwidget.h custombwidget.cpp CustomBWidget.ui
)

qt_add_executable(Demo
    MANUAL_FINALIZATION
    ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
)
target_include_directories(Demo PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(Demo PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)
qt_finalize_executable(Demo)
```

I expect that both widgets would be placed in the QStackWidget and have a proper layout so that it fits within the main widget.

Comment: You are only setting the main layout, but the pages of the stacked widget have none. If you want a predefined layout for those blank pages, just add a random widget to each page, set the layout for that page, and remove the widget. Otherwise, just create and set a proper layout by code.

Comment: Note that if you *do* use a layout in those pages, we need to know what you actually do, so in that case please provide a [mre].

Comment: The designer doesn't show any ability to create a layout for the QStackWidget that contains the pages. The docs say that this widget already has a QStackLayout built in, https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstackedwidget.html#details . Why would I need to set it as well?

Comment: I never said that you need to set a layout for the stacked widget, but *for its pages*. As said, if you want to set a default layout for them, do the procedure above for each page. If, otherwise, the layout of those pages has to be set from the actual widgets (those you're promoting), then you have to properly set **their main layout** in those classes, which you probably failed to do. If you need further help, provide a MRE (or the actual UI) for those `SurveyIncomeExpensesWidget` and `SurveyDistributionWidget` classes.

Comment: I've added the additional UIs for those pages, as an MRE in this case may demonstrate the issue, but not help solve the problem.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the issue is in `SurveyDistributionWidget` (specifically the contents of the scroll area). Then we need to know how you fill that widget.

Comment: The `SurveyDistributionWidget` itself I think is fine because when it is set to be displayed first, everything is laid out as intended. However, in the flow of things, it's meant to be the second thing shown. It is only when it is the second widget to be shown, that it looks like the shown in the above images. If you'd like to see the full code it's available here: https://foss.heptapod.net/JohnMS/drn/-/tree/topic/default/10-SurveyGUI/src/desktop-ui/internal?ref_type=heads .

Comment: Since the problem is in the second page (`SurveyDistributionWidget`), then the problem is there, most importantly how you populate it. So, we need a MRE, and that should be included in the question, not using external resources that may become unavailable, thus making the question invalid.

Comment: I don't see how the issue could be the inside `SurveyDistributionWidget`. When it is the first widget shown, it is shown correctly, that is what the very last image displays. It is that the second widget shown is not correctly displayed. How then could it be fine in one and not in the other?

Comment: There are many possible reasons for that, including issues in laying out widgets (the layout of child widgets is normally not activated until its managed widget is shown the first time, and some complex layouts may even cause delayed resize events), or a wrong layout usage on your part, and not excluding (while unlikely) a possible bug. That's why we need a MRE. I also suggest you to rephrase your post and clearly identify those widgets in the explanation, since terms like "page 1" and "page 2" become confusing especially if you then invert the display order.

Comment: Added a full demonstration of the issue.

Comment: Hi , You Can Put your program in GitHub and add that link to your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the way that the two widgets were being shown/hidden. Instead of showing/hiding directly, the key was to do something like the following:

```
this->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(this->stackedWidget->indexOf(this->page));
```